# I want to make my image static so when we move the screen it doesnt change the position?

Tags: html, css

I want to make my website to be able to scroll when I resize the windows. It already fixed vertically but when i moved horizontally the position of my element is change. 
[I want to be able to scroll down when i resize my window screen like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPukM.jpg)

[But when I resize my windows horizontally my div icon become smaller and the position i changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf3cp.png)

Here is my code for my background.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/background-photo.jpg) no-repeat; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:#245528;

}
```

Here is my CSS for my div container code.

```
#page-wrap { width: 50%; margin: 1% auto; padding:1%; position: fixed; }
#fixed { margin-left: 33%;margin-top:8% ; position: fixed; }
#fixed1 { margin-left: 34%;margin-top:13% ;position: fixed; }
#fixed2 { margin-left: 34%;margin-top:19%; position: fixed;}
#fixed3 { margin-left: 27%; margin-top:40% ; position: fixed;}
#fixed4 { margin-left: 27%; margin-top:2% ; position: fixed;}`
```

Here is how I write my div.

```
 <div id="page-wrap">
       <div id="fixed4">
                <a href="contactX.html"><img src="images/contact.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width=35%></a>                    
            </div>
            <div id="fixed">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/news.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width=35%></a>
            </div>

            <div id="fixed1">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/success.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width=35% ></a>
            </div>

            <div id="fixed2">
            <a href="slide.html"><img src="images/product.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width=35%></a>
            </div>

            <div id="fixed3">
            <a href="aboutus.html"><img src="images/company_profile.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width=35%></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what your issue exactly is.

Comment: @EricWiener i want to be able to scroll my website when i resize my browser screen. And i want it to be fixed place so the size and my resolution wont matter at all to all my img size.